# As well as my home page on personnel interview, I would like to be able to add a link to my GitHub repository

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks

This could be solved by perhaps have a public repositories fields
Public Repositories: GitHub: BBBB
                     SourceForge: CCCC

or maybe having the ability to have more than one website link which can be named, like
website    Homepage:            AAAA
           GitHub:              BBBB
           SourceForge:         CCCC
           My Furies Home Page: EEEE

The public repositories fields seems like a good idea as I am sure a lot of people have public repositories.

Another possibility is as well as the standard fields let people add there own,
GitHub:              BBBB
Favourite pastime:   Dressing Cats up as victorian era authors and publishing their photos on the internet.

Comment: You know, that's what you have the info box for.

Answer (score 4):

As @slhck said, Info boxes were created for this problem. You can simply have something like this:

> Developer at X
>
> - Blog: *your link*
> - GitHub: *your link*
> - SourceForge: *your link*
> - Really cool project: *your link*
>
> Other interesting bits
>
> - Favourite pastime: Dressing Cats up as victorian era authors and
>     publishing their photos on the internet.
> - Favorite Color: Red

I use this in my profile to advertise projects of mine and list what I know. Others like [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) use it to show who they are and some humor.

Really creating fields for this would be pointless. Not only would you have to either A) have a huge list of possible fields (and deal with tons of feature requests for new ones) or B) handle the complexity (and abuse) of custom fields. Besides, my eyes naturally gravitate to large different colored infobox after the avatar, they are very prominent. The center bits of info don't attract as much attention.

Comment: OK fair enough, but why was this voted down -9 points, it not like it an inappropriate question there are just good reasons as to why the answers it's not needed.

Comment: @Nathan Here on meta downvotes mean they disagree with your proposal, not that its a bad question.